# is there any size $N\cdot N$Sudoku Puzzle where the smaller $\sqrt N\cdot\sqrt N$ squares all form magic squares

Tags: recreational-mathematics, magic-square, sudoku

Any $N\cdot N$ Sudoku Puzzle has $N$ squares size $\sqrt N\cdot\sqrt N$ that each have the numbers $1$ to $N$ in them.Is there a sudoku puzzle of any size that have magic squares for all of these sub-squares? I think it will be inevitable for large enough $N$, since there will be more possible Sudokus.

Comment: Note that $N$ should be even because in odd size magic squares the centre number is forced and would conflict with sudoku rules.

Comment: @zwim not if we require magicness only for rows and columns. So rhen we can also find a standard 9 by 9 with this ...

Comment: No @zwim.  Only for order 3 does the magic square have a fixed center.  In fact if we choose an order where there are pandiagonal squares, such as order 5, all the blocks may be constructed from translations of a single such pandiagonal square.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes, there is a solution for $16\cdot16$](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/2206/10089):

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6C52f.png]

Answer (score 0):

In the 5×5/25×25 case you can set up a pandiagonal structure, as in the picture below.  Note carefully that only five translations of a single magic square (which is itself pandiagonal with respect to addition) are used, yet the array has all the required Sudoku properties and is also pandiagonal as a Latin square!

[image]

(Picture generated by the author.)